# Refreshing form -> uploading data

Tags: php, page-refresh

I have a problem with my PHP form. Whenever I refresh the page, the old data automatically inserted to my database. My codes are:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET['send'])){
      isset($_GET['name'])?$name = $_GET['name']:"";
      isset($_GET['score'])?$score = $_GET['score']:0;

      $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
             mysql_select-db('student',$con) or die(mysql_error());
      $qry = mysql_query('INSERT INTO student(name, score) VALUES('$name', $score)') or die(mysql_error());

      $display = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM student',$con) or die(mysql_error());
      echo '<table border=1>';
      while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($display)){
          echo '<tr>';
          echo "<td>$rows['id']</td>";
          echo "<td>$rows['name']</td>";
          echo "<td>$rows['score']</td>";
          echo '</tr>';
      } 
      echo '</table>';
    }
    ?>
```

please help me solve this problem.

Comment: ofcourse...your insert query is executed everytime you refresh it.<br/>try making it that if a certain condition is meet..the insert query is executed... try putting it in an if.

Comment: You have to check your from submit.I think. http://www.webmaster-forums.net/web-programming-and-application-development/posting-php-self-stop-dublicate-insert-refresh

Answer (score 2):

A common way to prevent duplicate form submission is to make use of the [Post/Redirect/Get Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

You would need to change your forms method to **Post** then. After successful form submission you redirect to the form again but making the redirect a get request. The form will be reset then (empty values).

**Edit:**

Now as I see it, your script can actually do something similar: After insertion into the mysql Database you can redirect it to itself removing the get parameters:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['send'])){
  isset($_GET['name'])?$name = $_GET['name']:"";
  isset($_GET['score'])?$score = $_GET['score']:0;

  $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
         mysql_select-db('student',$con) or die(mysql_error());
  $qry = mysql_query('INSERT INTO student(name, score) VALUES('$name', $score)') or die(mysql_error());
  header('Location: myscriptsurl.php');
  exit;
}

$display = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM student',$con) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<table border=1>';
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($display)){
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td>$rows['id']</td>";
  echo "<td>$rows['name']</td>";
  echo "<td>$rows['score']</td>";
  echo '</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: guy, this seems to be displaying the result in another page. However, my purpose is to insert and display results on the same page

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn: You need to put your pages link in there. As I don't know it, I've put a placeholder in there ;)

Comment: hmm, I tried, but it still in the manner of displaying in another page

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn: The premise of the example code is, that it's assumed it's part of your "one" page that both has the form and the results displayed underneath. If that is not the case and you're still not sharing the URL of that page, there is nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a problem.
And since you cannot avoid a refresh of the screen...

If you are doing a form post, you might consider sending a location
header AFTER you inserted the record:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="number">
<input type="sumbit">
</form>
```

then from process.php:
// do you usual inserts in the database based on the post

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/thanks.php");
// do not forget the exit, since your script will run on without it.
exit;
```

In that way your script will process the posting, and then redirects the
browser to `thanks.php.`
A reload of `thanks.php` will not result in a fresh db insert.

Answer (score 1):

**U have used GET method so every time page refresh it will fetch the value from URL.
Try using POST method...It will solve your Problem and don't forget to Put Condition for POST**

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
   /* Your Insert Code */

}
```